# How to disable the automatic insertion of <br> tag in p:editor?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, editor

I use PrimeFaces v4.0.24. Is there a way to disable the automatic adding `<br>` in [`<p:editor>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/editor.xhtml)? It's destroying markup and validation.

Answer (score -1):

You Can customize the class org.primefaces.component.editor based on your requirement.
You can create your own package org.primefaces.component.editor by extracting its class.just find out which line of code can be modified so that your requirement can fulfill.